# Specify frame rate while reading a video using skvideo.io.vread

Tags: python, video

I'm reading a video using `skvideo.io.vread`

```
import skvideo.io
video_frames = skvideo.io.vread(video_filepath)
```

My video has a frame rate of 50fps. But I want to read the video at 4fps, I mean I need to read only 4 frames per second of the video. Is there any option to read at specified frame rate or do I have to manually discard extra frames read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`skvideo.io.vread` takes input parameters in form of dictionary. So, you can pass the frame rate like this:

```
import skvideo.io

video_frames = skvideo.io.vread(video_filepath, inputdict={'-r' : 4}) # Specify frame rate
```

Here is the official documentation:
http://www.scikit-video.org/stable/examples/io.html

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you would have to discard the extra frames manually.

Although something you can try: The documentation for vread says that you can pass in inputdict as an argument, which is passed to the FFMpeg reader. [This example](http://www.scikit-video.org/stable/examples/didactic.html#selectively-manipulating-frames) shows how the rate can be set by the reader. I think this would most likely result in the video being sped up or slowed down, however.

```
import skvideo.io

rate = 4
video_frames = skvideo.io.vread(video_filepath, \
    inputdict={'-r': rate})
```